# Add anchor element in middle of text of div jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dynamically create a div which displays a message that contains a dynamically created anchor tag in the middle of the message.

```
var user = "@MJGwater";
var message1 = "Tweet was created by" ;
var message2 = "on Tuesday."

var $a = $("<a></a>")
$a.html(user);
$a.attr("href", "http://twitter.com/MJGwater")

var $div = $("<div></div>")
$div.text(message1 + " " + anchor element + " " + message2);


$div.appendTo($("body"));
```

I can type a.html() to display the text @MJGwater in the middle of the message, but I want the entire anchor tag to be in the middle of the div so my link works.

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.append()` to append DOM element:

```js
var user = "@MJGwater";
var message1 = "Tweet was created by ";
var message2 = " on Tuesday."

var $anchor = $("<a/>")
  .text(user)
  .attr("href", "http://twitter.com/" + user.substr(1));

$("<div/>")
  .append(message1)
  .append($anchor)
  .append(message2)
  .appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```